# Python 3.3 binary to hex function

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, hex

```
def bintohex(path):
    hexvalue = []
    file = open(path,'rb')
    while True:
        buffhex = pkmfile.read(16)
        bufflen = len(buffhex)
        if bufflen == 0: break
        for i in range(bufflen):
            hexvalue.append("%02X" % (ord(buffhex[i])))
```

I am making a function that will return a list of hex values of a specific file. However, this function doesn't work properly in Python 3.3. How should I modify this code?

```
File "D:\pkmfile_web\pkmtohex.py", line 12, in bintohex hexvalue.append("%02X" % (ord(buffhex[i]))) TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Comment: Define "does not work properly"

Comment: File "D:\pkmfile_web\pkmtohex.py", line 12, in bintohex
    hexvalue.append("%02X" % (ord(buffhex[i])))
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: Add that information to the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

There's a module for that :-)

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'abc')
'616263'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, indexing a `bytes` object returns the integer value; there is no need to call `ord`:

```
hexvalue.append("%02X" % buffhex[i])
```

Additionally, there is no need to be manually looping over the indices. Just loop over the `bytes` object. I've also modified it to use `format` rather than `%`:

```
buffhex = pkmfile.read(16)
if not buffhex:
for byte in buffhex:
    hexvalue.append(format(byte, '02X'))
```

You may want to even make `bintohex` a generator. To do that, you could start `yield`ing values:

```
yield format(byte, '02X')
```